# Calling Python scripts from Java. Should I use Docker?

Tags: java, python, docker

We have a Java application in our project and what we want is to call some Python script and return results from it. What is the best way to do this?

We want to isolate Python execution to avoid affecting Java application at all. Probably, Dockerizing Python is the best solution. I don't know any other way.

Then, a question is how to call it from Java.

As far as I understand there are several ways:

1. start some web-server inside Docker which accepts REST calls from Java App and runs Python scripts and returns results to Java via REST too.
2. handle request and response via Docker CLI somehow.
3. use Java Docker API to send REST request to Docker which then converted by Docker to Stdin/Stdout of Python script inside Docker.

What is the most effective and correct way to connect Java App with Python, running inside Docker?

Comment: I think exposing a rest api in python and calling rest apis from java will be better approach, as there will be no any external dependecies (docker apis). You can later on call rest api from anywhere not only from java in case you need.

Comment: How much isolation do you need between the python and java code?

Comment: While you could use REST, I might suggest an RPC framework that can generate methods and clients for both languages

Comment: jrtapsell, I dont want Python code to be able to influence Java App. In terms of CPU, RAM, file system access these two parts of my setup should be independent.

Comment: Would definitely agree with using a RPC for cross-language API invoking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need docker for this. There are a couple of options, you should choose depending on what your Java application is doing.

1. If the Java application is a **client** - based on swing, weblaunch, or providing UI directly - you will want to turn the python functionality to be wrapped in REST/HTTP calls.
2. If the Java application is a **server/webapp** - executing within Tomcat, JBoss or other application container - you should simply wrap the python scrip inside a `exec` call. See the Java Runtime and ProcessBuilder API for this purpose.

Comment: I see no reason swing, or other, cannot also shell out to Python scripts

Comment: Ah, I really meant to call out client-side application vs server side. So if your application is running on the customers laptop, you don't really want to spawn new processes there for trivial purposes as these.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense

Comment: Thanks Timir! My application is a server, launched on some application container. The reason why I want to use Docker is that my application should not depend on Python script execution results. Python script may consume all memory, delete some file on disk, consume all CPU  - but the main Java application should never notice this. Thats why I suppose Docker is a good option.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [OpenFaas](https://github.com/openfaas/faas) to dockerize your python scripts with a webserver on top.

You can use the full OpenFaas stack to create single API functions mapped to single containers or you can use only the OpenFaas web component.

A simple `Dockerfile` could be something like:

```
FROM python:3.4-alpine

ADD . /workdir
WORKDIR /workdir

ADD https://github.com/openfaas/faas/releases/download/0.7.9/fwatchdog /usr/bin
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/fwatchdog

ENV fprocess="python yourPythonScript.py"
CMD ["fwatchdog"]
```

Build it and run it:

```
$ docker build . -t dockerized-python-script
[....]
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 dockerized-python-script
```

And you are ready to "talk" to your script via http with plaintext parameters:

```
$ curl yourserver:8080 -d "param1 param2 param3"
Some output from your script
```

If you want to talk JSON, you'll need to modify `yourPythonScript.py` accordingly to manage input and output.